# Run threaded function from another function in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I ran through several other questions and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
What I want to do is run function zapisNoveho i background, so the main task doesn't have to wait.

```
#Otevírání
if(obj_stav-obj_stav_novy == -1):
    zapis(obj,3)
    dbChanger.zapisDb(obj,3)
    #display.checkState()
    #cvaknutí relé zde
    th = threading.Thread(target=zapisNoveho,args=(obj,obj_stav_novy))
    th.start()

def zapisNoveho(obj,obj_stav_novy):
   #Zápis nového stavu po odmlce
   sleep(10)
   zapis(obj,obj_stav_novy)
   dbChanger.zapisDb(obj,obj_stav_novy)
```

From what I see in log, the main program is waiting for the sleep part.
Can you please tell what am I doing wrong? Is it better to use Asyncio for this case?
Thank you!

Comment: This is not quite a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is not clear what you mean by the "main program is waiting for the sleep part." The *main thread* will not complete until any threads you started complete (unless those threads are *daemon* threads, which your started thread is not). So if `th.start()` is the last executable statement of your main thread (and it is not clear that it is from what little you posted), you *will* now block. But if you have statements that follow, you should not be blocking on the `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

> the main program is waiting for the sleep part.

It is likely that it isn't the *main* program waiting for the `sleep`, but the thread *th* that you have started. This might not be obvious from logs, because logs from both threads will go to the same terminal window, so I recommend to add a thread identifier to your log lines (e.g. via `threading.get_ident()`) so that you can clearly see which thread is writing which line of the log.